# Error in argument of parstInt and isNaN function

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

Why there is error when im passing argument in the parstInt and isNaN function saying argument of type void is not assignable to type string how can i solve this

```
var u = rx.Observable.interval(400).take(6).map((i)=>{
['2', 'sdf', '4', '8fj', '6'][i]
});
var x = u.map(function(e){ 
parseInt(e);             //error on e
}).filter(r => !isNaN(r)) //error on r
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `return parseInt(e);`?

Comment: no, it still giving error at e

Comment: It would help to know what error, especially since the bottom part of your code (without using rx) [appears to be fine](https://jsfiddle.net/1schLuch/) with the `return`.

Comment: Error is argument of type void is not assignable to number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array. – via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Therefore, the `.map()` callback requires a value to be returned, otherwise it maps the item to `undefined`. Use either `return parseInt(e, 10);` inside your `function` or use an arrow function, which will return by default. (and [always use a radix with parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt))

```
var u = rx.Observable.interval(400).take(6).map((i) => {
    return ['2', 'sdf', '4', '8fj', '6'][i]
});

var x = u.map(e => parseInt(e, 10)).filter(r => !isNaN(r));
```

If you don't need the intermediate step, you can reduce this even further and drop one loop by parsing inside the filter function.

```
var x = u.filter(r => !isNaN(parseInt(r, 10)));
```

**EDIT**
I just realized this is actually a TypeScript question.

The error occurs because the array you use to map your Observable to is one item short. Therefore the mapped array will contain:

['2', 'sdf', '4', '8fj', '6', undefined];

parseInt() expects the first param to be a string. In plain JS, it will try to convert to a string, it seems TypeScript may handle things a little different.

To fix that as well, you could update the callback of your first map like this:

```
var u = rx.Observable.interval(400).take(6).map((i) => {
    return ['2', 'sdf', '4', '8fj', '6'][i] || '';
});
```

Comment: if we dont return why it will be undefined

Comment: As quoted: The map() method creates a new array with **the results of calling a provided function** on every element in this array. Therefore, if your callback doesn't `return` a result, it becomes undefined.